# Why compute row_number() order by monotonically_increasing_id() in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

It is suggested that you can ['generate unique increasing numeric values'](https://kb.databricks.com/sql/gen-unique-increasing-values.html#combine-monotonically_increasing_id-with-row_number-for-two-columns) by

```sql
select row_number() over (order by monotonically_increasing_id()) from /* ... */
```

But you can just as well do this:

```sql
select row_number() over (order by 1) from /* ... */
```

What benefit does using `monotonically_increasing_id()` provide in this case?

Answer (score 0):

`monotonically_increasing_id()` guarantees that the ids are increasing but does not guarantee they will be consecutive.

> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but **not consecutive.**